# Powershell string concatenation of expressions

Tags: powershell, concatenation

I'm using a ternary expression as shown in this example:

```
$a = 1
$x = if ($a -eq 1) { "one" } else {"not one" }
$t = "The answer is: " + $x
write-host $t
```

This works as I would expect. What I would like to do in my real situation though, is to assign directly to `$t` without the intermediate step of first assigning the expression to `$x`, as if I could do this:

```
$a = 1
$t = "The answer is: " + (if ($a -eq 1) { "one" } else {"not one" })
write-host $t
```

However, I get an error on the assignment line,

```
if : The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:31
+     $t = "The answer is: " + (if ($a -eq 1) { "one" } else {"not one" ...
+                               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (if:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

(I've tried with an without the `(...)` brackets: same error.) Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but my google-fu isn't helping today. I can see how to concatenate [constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113413/how-to-concatenate-strings-and-variables-in-powershell) [and](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-us/4e370143-eb34-4acc-96a2-301b102e69ec/concatenate-strings-and-variables) [variables](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=powershell%20string%20concatenation), but nothing seems to explain how to concatenate constants and expressions.

Can you point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *so* close. :)

You need to [use the `$`](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens) to declare the statement's return value as a variable.

So:

```
$a = 1
$t = "The answer is: " + $(if ($a -eq 1) { "one" } else { "not one" })
write-host $t
```

Or perhaps as two lines, utilizing Write-Host's [formatting options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/2008.06.windowspowershell.aspx):

```
$a = 1
write-host ("{0} {1}" -f "The answer is:", $(if ($a -eq 1) { "one" } else { "not one" }))
```

Comment: Thank you. So `if()` isn't an expression; even in this context it's really a statement? To me that's rather counterintuitive, but I really appreciate the pointers to more info. (I'm coming at Powershell from years of Unix/Linux mixed with (un)healthy doses of C, Perl, and even VB.)

Comment: All I can say is that PowerShell can be weird about it's variables due to it trying to guess the appropriate context - get used to it. :)  Along the lines of displaying variables, I'd advise reading the difference between using `'` and `"` to surround strings in PS - it makes a difference when dealing with variable expansion, and can make a PS newbie bang his head off the wall for a while if they' not aware of the nuances. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm very comfortable with the difference between quotes; it's the same in the Unix/Linux shell world.